# Spring framework spring-test v5.2.0 MergedAnnotations Search Strategy problem

Tags: java, spring

Here we have a problem in an IT test after upgrading spring-test to 5.2.0.RELEASE.

The Following code :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
// @WebMvcTest
public class TestedControllerIT {

    private static final ObjectMapper JSON_OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    private static final String TOPIC = "topic";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private TestedRepository testedRepository;

    @Before
    public void init() {

        testedRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReinjectError()
            throws Exception {

        // Given
        LinkedHashMap kafkaMessage = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        kafkaMessage.put("orderNumber", "orderNumber");
        kafkaMessage.put("recordedDate", 1564652757990L);
        kafkaMessage.put("creationDate", 1564652546217L);

        final RejetTechnique rejetTechnique = RejetTechnique.builder()
                                                            .creationDate(LocalDateTime.now())
                                                            .id("1")
                                                            .offset(12L)
                                                            .topic(TOPIC)
                                                            .stackTrace("")
                                                            .kafkaMessage(kafkaMessage)
                                                            .build();
        testedRepository.save(rejetTechnique);

        // When
        final MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/rejet-technique/reinjection"))
                                        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(200))
                                        .andReturn();

        //Then
        assertThat(result.getResponse().getContentAsString()).isEqualTo("{\"status\":\"OK\"}");
        assertThat(testedRepository.findAll().size()).isEqualTo(0);

        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(TOPIC, 0);
        ConsumerRecords<String, Object> records;
        try (KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer(props)) {
            List<TopicPartition> topics = Collections.singletonList(topicPartition);
            kafkaConsumer.assign(topics);
            kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(topics);
            long current = kafkaConsumer.position(topicPartition);
            kafkaConsumer.seek(topicPartition, current - 1);

            Duration duration = Duration.of(1000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
            records = kafkaConsumer.poll(duration);
        }

        String resultRecordValue = (String) records.records(topicPartition).get(0).value();

        assertThat(resultRecordValue).isEqualTo(convertMessageToJson(kafkaMessage));
    }

    private String convertMessageToJson(final Object message)
            throws JsonProcessingException {

        return JSON_OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(message);
    }
}
```

Is given us the Following error :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
>
> at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils.buildMergedTestPropertySources(TestPropertySourceUtils.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:386)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.(SpringRunner.java:49)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>     at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:766)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1077)
>     ... 25 more

Notice : It works perfectly until release 5.2.0.RC1 of [spring-test](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test).

It seems related to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23378).

Does anyone have any clue ?

Thanks for the help =)

Comment: I experienced the exact same problem. The root cause was that I was having two different versions of Spring for different artifacts. Check your pom.xml and standardize the version of Spring for all artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to have consistent Spring versions in project.

I resolved my issue by using spring boot.